# Separating date formatted as Jul 1, 2020

Tags: r, string

Need help again separating a column with dates in RStudio

I would like to have three separate columns with Year, Month and, Day

It may be worth noting that the column is currently a character type

Thank you for your efforts!

```r
str(fifa21_raw_data$Joined)

chr [1:18979] "Jul 1, 2004" "Jul 10, 2018" "Jul 16, 2014" ...

dput(fifa21_raw_data$Joined[1:20])

c("Jul 1, 2004", "Jul 10, 2018", "Jul 16, 2014", "Aug 30, 2015", 
"Aug 3, 2017", "Jul 1, 2014", "Jul 1, 2018", "Jul 19, 2018", 
"Jul 1, 2017", "Jul 1, 2016", "Jan 1, 2018", "Jul 1, 2014", "Jul 11, 2013", 
"Aug 9, 2018", "Jul 1, 2011", "Jul 9, 2009", "Aug 1, 2005", "Jul 28, 2011", 
"Jul 16, 2016", "Jul 1, 2015")
```

Comment: Wow thank you all very much for the assistance! Truly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the month as (e.g.) `"Jul"`, then simply:

```r
do.call(rbind, strsplit(vec, "[, ]+"))
#       [,1]  [,2] [,3]  
#  [1,] "Jul" "1"  "2004"
#  [2,] "Jul" "10" "2018"
#  [3,] "Jul" "16" "2014"
#  [4,] "Aug" "30" "2015"
#  [5,] "Aug" "3"  "2017"
#  [6,] "Jul" "1"  "2014"
#  [7,] "Jul" "1"  "2018"
#  [8,] "Jul" "19" "2018"
#  [9,] "Jul" "1"  "2017"
# [10,] "Jul" "1"  "2016"
# [11,] "Jan" "1"  "2018"
# [12,] "Jul" "1"  "2014"
# [13,] "Jul" "11" "2013"
# [14,] "Aug" "9"  "2018"
# [15,] "Jul" "1"  "2011"
# [16,] "Jul" "9"  "2009"
# [17,] "Aug" "1"  "2005"
# [18,] "Jul" "28" "2011"
# [19,] "Jul" "16" "2016"
# [20,] "Jul" "1"  "2015"
```

If you need it as a number-month, then

```r
as.Date(vec, format = "%b %d, %Y") |>
  as.character() |>
  strsplit("-") |>
  do.call(rbind, args=_)
#       [,1]   [,2] [,3]
#  [1,] "2004" "07" "01"
#  [2,] "2018" "07" "10"
#  [3,] "2014" "07" "16"
#  [4,] "2015" "08" "30"
#  [5,] "2017" "08" "03"
#  [6,] "2014" "07" "01"
#  [7,] "2018" "07" "01"
#  [8,] "2018" "07" "19"
#  [9,] "2017" "07" "01"
# [10,] "2016" "07" "01"
# [11,] "2018" "01" "01"
# [12,] "2014" "07" "01"
# [13,] "2013" "07" "11"
# [14,] "2018" "08" "09"
# [15,] "2011" "07" "01"
# [16,] "2009" "07" "09"
# [17,] "2005" "08" "01"
# [18,] "2011" "07" "28"
# [19,] "2016" "07" "16"
# [20,] "2015" "07" "01"
```

These both return a `matrix` with three columns, you can convert to `data.frame` and name the columns with something like:

```r
... |>
  as.data.frame() |>
  setNames(c("Year", "Month", "Day"))
```

and, if needed, `cbind` or otherwise assign to your current frame.

Comment: Thank you so much for specifying the month format! The latter is what I needed but failed to specify. Good insight!

Answer (score 1):

Using `fifa` from the Note at the end load dplyr and tidyr and convert the dates to standard yyyy-mm-dd format and then use `separate` to separate and convert them into numeric columns.

```
library(dlyr)
library(tidyr)

fifa %>%
  mutate(dates = format(as.Date(dates, "%b %d, %Y"))) %>%
  separate(dates, into = c("year", "month", "day"), 
    convert = TRUE, remove = FALSE)
```

giving

```
        dates year month day
1  2004-07-01 2004     7   1
2  2018-07-10 2018     7  10
3  2014-07-16 2014     7  16
4  2015-08-30 2015     8  30
5  2017-08-03 2017     8   3
6  2014-07-01 2014     7   1
...snip...
```

or using base R

```
fifa |>
  transform(dates = format(as.Date(dates, "%b %d, %Y"))) |>
  list(. = _) |>
  with(cbind(., read.table(text = .$dates, sep = "-",
    col.names = c("year", "month", "day"))))
```

### Note

```
fifa <- data.frame(
  dates = c(
    "Jul 1, 2004", "Jul 10, 2018", "Jul 16, 2014", "Aug 30, 2015", "Aug 3, 2017",
    "Jul 1, 2014", "Jul 1, 2018", "Jul 19, 2018", "Jul 1, 2017", "Jul 1, 2016",
    "Jan 1, 2018", "Jul 1, 2014", "Jul 11, 2013", "Aug 9, 2018", "Jul 1, 2011",
    "Jul 9, 2009", "Aug 1, 2005", "Jul 28, 2011", "Jul 16, 2016", "Jul 1, 2015"
  )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `scan` + `sub` like below

```
> t(matrix(scan(text = sub(",", "", vec), what = "", quiet = TRUE), 3))
      [,1]  [,2] [,3]
 [1,] "Jul" "1"  "2004"
 [2,] "Jul" "10" "2018"
 [3,] "Jul" "16" "2014"
 [4,] "Aug" "30" "2015"
 [5,] "Aug" "3"  "2017"
 [6,] "Jul" "1"  "2014"
 [7,] "Jul" "1"  "2018"
 [8,] "Jul" "19" "2018"
 [9,] "Jul" "1"  "2017"
[10,] "Jul" "1"  "2016"
[11,] "Jan" "1"  "2018"
[12,] "Jul" "1"  "2014"
[13,] "Jul" "11" "2013"
[14,] "Aug" "9"  "2018"
[15,] "Jul" "1"  "2011"
[16,] "Jul" "9"  "2009"
[17,] "Aug" "1"  "2005"
[18,] "Jul" "28" "2011"
[19,] "Jul" "16" "2016"
[20,] "Jul" "1"  "2015"
```